# vuejs add filter to paginated list generated by json response

Tags: vuejs2

I´ve just started with Vue and stuck with a basic question. Following this [tutorial](https://medium.com/@obapelumi/pagination-with-vuejs-1f505ce8d15b) I´m receiving posts as json. The list of post gets paginated

**displayedPosts()** calculates and returns shown posts per page

```
methods: {
...
paginate (posts) {
   let page = this.page;
   let perPage = this.perPage;
   let from = (page * perPage) - perPage;
   let to = (page * perPage);
   return posts.slice(from, to);
}, 
...
computed: {
  displayedPosts () {
    return this.paginate(this.posts);
  },
...
```

Then Template is bound to displayedPosts:

```
<div class="col-md-4" v-for="post in displayedPosts">
  <div class="card mb-4 box-shadow post-cards">
...
```

Now I´d like to add an input to filter the whole list.

```
// template input
<input type="search" placeholder="Search..." autofocus  v-model="search">

// method to filter model
computed: {
  ...
  filteredItems () {
    return this.posts.filter(item => {  
      return item.title.toLowerCase().indexOf(this.search.toLowerCase()) > -1
  })
}
```

In summary, the pagination does only allow a certain amount of items per page. The filter should hide all list items and only show posts which contain given string.

In case my filter method is correct how would I bind filteredItems to the template for loop as this is already bound to displayesPosts()?

Thanks a lot for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can change `displayedPosts`:

```
computed: {
  displayedPosts () {
    return this.paginate(this.filteredItems);
  },
  filteredItems () {
    return this.posts.filter(item => {  
      return item.title.toLowerCase().indexOf(this.search.toLowerCase()) > -1
    })
  }
}
```

Comment: Ahh sorry I was a bit to fast when setting `displayedPosts () {
      return this.paginate(this.filteredItems);
    },`pagination stops working ;( (but search is working )

Comment: What's the behavior of pagination now? In there any error on developer console?

Comment: Hey @ittus thanks for your help. It seams there is some confusion with the model after using the next pagination button (which fires displayedPosts()) an item is not shown anymore, see: https://vimeo.com/280224553 maybe I should reset the list on every new search ?